# Nginx ingress controller still redirect to SSL

Tags: kubernetes

I am experiencing this issue. My application needs to receive connection under SSL only with WebSocket. HTTP requests should be forced to not being redirected. My ingress configuration is

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: in-camonline
 namespace: cl5
 annotations: 
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  nginx.org/websocket-services: "svc-ws-api"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
  ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "ClientIP"
spec:
 tls:
  - hosts:
    - foo.bar.com
    secretName: cl5-secret
 rules:
 - host:  foo.bar.com
   http:
    paths:
     - path: /socket.io
       backend:
        serviceName: svc-ws-api
        servicePort: 8000
     - path: /
       backend:
        serviceName: svc-http-service
        servicePort: 80
```

I also disabled the `ssl-redirect` globally adding an item into the ConfigMap

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
data:
        #use-proxy-protocol: "false"
 ssl-redirect: "false"
```

Now if I do request using curl, requests won't being redirected. If I try to run my front-end application every request after the WSS will be forced to being redirected to use HTTPS

```
Request URL: http://foo.bar.com/2/symbols
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 307 Internal Redirect
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Any suggestion about how to achieve that?

Comment: Have you checked the nginx.conf and made sure redirect is disabled?

Comment: Hi @crou, sorry about the late response :). The redirect is disabled. The strange behavior is that only requests after the https made by socket.io are forced to be redirected. Not the 2 before.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I sorted it out. If someone is reading this, easy you are not alone!

Jokes aside, `nginx-controller` was setting header `Strict-Transport-Security` after the first HTTPS call (socket.io polling in my case). This header forces the browser to use TLS for the next requests. You can read more about this header here https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security

What I did is to disable the option adding the entry `hsts: false` on the `ingress-controller`'s ConfigMap object. 
You can find more here https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#hsts
Hope this can help you :)

Comment: Not even this is working for me: 

```kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
data:
  hsts: "false"
```

Comment: So do you have the problem still?

Comment: I got this working after setting both hsts: false and ss-redirect: false

Answer (score 2):

There is another solution.

If you want to disable HSTS just make the max-age zero. like this!!

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |  
if ($scheme = https) {   
  add_header  Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0;";  
}
```

link : https://justin-g.tistory.com/176

Comment: For me, this added a second STS header, and Chrome picked up the first anyway. However, this did the trick: `more_clear_headers 'Strict-Transport-Security';`